# Is it possible to save data currently in RAM to a disk for analysis?

Tags: memory

I would like to know if it is possible to copy whatever data is in active memory (RAM) to disk, and if so would it be readable?

Example: I open a image in an image preview program. I use RAM-copy program to copy all of my active memory to disk. Somewhere on that disk now is another copy of the image that was opened in the program (as well as whatever else was running).

I'm not too worried about instability of the running program or corruption of data in memory as I would be doing this on a virtual machine with a copy of the actual data. I'd just like to know if this is possible.

Edit: Windows 7/8 are my options for OS.

Comment: It's called a memory dump but the program has to support it in order to do so.  The memory space of an application is only known by the program and the OS.

Comment: Depends on the OS, Windows ?

Comment: It seems possible, but I have a feeling recent versions of Windows won't allow it. @Ramhound check out this [workaround to the address problem](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/15817/#msg78481) (more in the last comment).

Comment: @Ofiris Thanks, forgot to specify. Added edit.

Comment: @Louis why did you send me to a beginner level website on C++ I have  multiple degrees in the subject.   a post from 2009 from a closed account with vague information does not apply to Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound It was in response to your comment on the memory space showing that if the "RAM-copy" program creates the process, it can figure out the address space. I wrote it before brack made his edit.